# Are there places in the gaming industry for people who are artistic and programmers?

Tags: software-engineering, art, jobs

Are there jobs, where you can switch from project to project between artistic roles (like sprite animations, concept art, visual development or even sound design) and programming roles?

Comment: Of course there are, in small studios. There are even single-man studios out there.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? "Yes or no" answers are generally not good questions for this site, and the implied follow-up question in your post is a list of companies like that, which is too broad to answer.

Comment: I hear they call it "QA". ;)

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a few edge cases:

1. Tech Artists are basically the people who work to bridge the gap between programming and art. The actual responsibilities of the role varies between teams and companies. One team might use a tech artist largely for building plugins for their art tools, another tech artist might be there who mostly does rigging, etc. You'll generally find tech artists on large teams, but not every team has them. This is probably the closest thing to an actual career path you'll find that combines both art and programming, but it's still a bit niche.
2. Prototyping. Being able to put together both the code *and* the art assets means you're in a really good spot to quickly build prototypes and iterate on them and you won't need a lot of outside support. That said, I'm not sure how many full-time jobs you'll find doing exclusively prototyping.
3. Start-ups with small teams. If you only have three to five people to build your entire game, you'll inherently have to cover multiple jobs. However, doing the job of two people carries the same stress level of, well, doing two jobs at once.
4. Solo indie development. One example game is [The Fall](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/189665092/the-fall-dark-story-driven-exploration-in-an-alien), which was basically made by an individual artist/programmer. I'm sure "make your own job" probably wasn't the answer you're looking for, but for the sake of completeness, it's worth noting.